# Retrieve twitter handle from contact

Tags: soql, rest-api

I am just getting started with Salesforce. I have enabled social contacts and linked one of the contacts to a Twitter account.

I can view the Twitter information on the contacts page from the Salesforce UI.

Is there a way I can retrieve the twitter handle which is stored internally by salesforce through SOQL? I am particularly interested from the REST APIs.

I tried querying the contacts object but did not fund any social/Twitter fields information out there.

Answer (score 7):

Accessing Social Contacts via Apex / API is not currently supported - there is an [idea for this](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000bOFxAAM)